# How to get the list of commit squashes and other alteration in a remote git repository

Tags: git

One particular GitHub upstream likes to change all dates of his commits to the first of the month.

In a cloned repository 'git log' only shows already altered commits, and 'git reflog' only shows local operations.

Is there a way to get a log of all commit squashes and other alterations done in a remote git repository?

Comment: When running `git fetch` you should see a list of the **forced updates** on the branches where that happened, the ID of the branch you that you knew of, and the new one. You can work from there.

Comment: 'git clone -v {url}'  doesn't show forced updates, and 'git fetch --show-forced-updates -v' then also doesn't show the list of forced updates, but I know that they are there.

Comment: If you are _cloning_, you will never know there was a forced update... at least, not from git straight. If you clone a repo.... and then one month later you **fetch**, then you would know if there were forced updates from fetch's output.

Comment: ... it's a tricky thing, just in case.... you might miss a forced update, for example, if a branch is created _after_ you clone (or last fetch) and a force-update is done on it _before_ you fetch... in this case you would only see a new branch. In general, it is considered rude to rewrite branch history for shared/public branches. It's a technical possibility, for sure, but it requires syncing among the people involved to know what's going on.